# How can I display my products from the cart?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, web-applications, laravel-7

I am using Melihovv ShoppingCart. I want to display all products inside cart but I couldn't. It shows the page but the products are not displaying.

Here is my code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   
    $cartItem = Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, $request->price, 1);
    return view('pages.cart')->with([
        'cartItem' => $request->cartItem
    ]);
    
}
```

And here is my view:

```
@if (!empty($cartItem) && count($cartItem) > 0)
    @foreach ($cartItem as $product)
        {{ $product }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: the `Cart::add` function does not looks like a function that would retreive data. Can you check what  `$cartItem` contains after this call ?

Comment: Yes when I use dd($cartItem) it shows all the request are being sent.

Comment: Then maybe `$product` ( in your view ) is an object rather than a string. You might want to access this object properties ( ex: `$product->name` or `$product['name']` )  rather than the object itself.

Comment: I fixed it by $cartContent = Cart::content();  this variable in my controller. Then loop through it in my views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to display the content of the cart, I think you should use

```
Cart::content()
```

Comment: Good luck bro .